# SSIS Dynamic column mapping in Excel Source and Destination SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a requirement where I need to dump my Excel data in SQL Server table. The excel files could be varying (different no. of columns each time) and for each excel source file a new table has to be created everytime in SQL Server.

I tried with SSIS tasks coming across things that Mapping between input/output columns has to be predefined in package. Also, the destination table I am dumping data in has to be present before executing "OLE DB Destination" task.

To overcome some limitations, I did few workarounds:

1. Created a sample table in my database with 50 columns (because that is the max. columns I can have at any point of time in my source excel).
2. Before package executes I take a copy of that sample table giving it a name as I need to have different tables for each source.
3. Passing Excel source file dynamically to package through c# code and SSIS Variables.

Since my initial mapping is between 50 input/output columns in package, when the next excel reaches package with less no. of columns, package execution fails.
I am running the package through c# code, also when i independently run this package in BIDS passing SSIS variable value there itself, it fails with invalid column references error.
I have to run this package through code and I can't everytime remap it on failure.

I can't paste a snapshot of Package as of my reputation on this forum. Its a simple package with 2 tasks i.e. 'Excel Source' & 'OLE DB Destination'. The only issue I am facing is with dynamic mapping in package. Rest all is working fine.

Please help me out with this. Thanks in Advance!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace SSRSReports
{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnpkg.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void btnpkg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newtableName = "DATA_MD0000001_I606423";

            string sourceExcel = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

            DataQuery(newtableName);

            RunPackage(sourceExcel, newtableName);
        }

        public void DataQuery(string newtableName)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            dc.ExecuteCommand("select * into" + " " + newtableName + " " + "from DummyTable");
        }

        public void RunPackage(string SourceExcelPath, string DestinationTableName)
        {
            string pkgLocation;
            Package pkg;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            Variables vars;

            lblResults.Visible = false;

            pkgLocation =
                @"C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DemoProject\DemoProject\Package.dtsx";
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

            vars = pkg.Variables;
        vars["SourceExcelFile"].Value = SourceExcelPath;
            vars["DestinationTableName"].Value = DestinationTableName;

            pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, vars, null, null, null);

            if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Success)
                lblResults.Text = "Package ran successfully";
            else
                lblResults.Text = "Package failed";

            lblResults.Visible = true;


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to refresh the mapping metadata each time to make it work. You may want to take a look at this article: http://www.selectsifiso.net/?p=288

Comment: Mapping each time would not be a possibility because I will have to run this package through asp.net page. The package will run in background on click of a button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836874/script-task-in-dft-doesnt-get-excecuted. This links solves the problem to greater extent. Thanks!!